# How to pull out the inbound certificate of a HTTPS endpoint in Mule

Tags: ssl-certificate, mule

Using Mule CE 3.5 I need to inspect the certificate provided with an inbound response.

I have a HTTPS endpoint configured and I've tried attaching a custom transformer to the response but it receives a `ReleasingInputStream` that contains the information I need but doesn't appear to expose it publicly. See the private `HttpMethod` property here: http://opensourcejavaphp.net/java/mule/org/mule/transport/http/ReleasingInputStream.java.html

I'm assuming there must be a simpler way of doing this. Are there any other ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for should be in the `PEER_CERTIFICATES` outbound property on the Mule message.

See: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.0/transports/http/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/http/HttpsMessageProcessTemplate.java#L44

Comment: Thanks for the fast and concise answer David. However when I try to access this property it is coming back as `null`. I know the certificate is definitely being passed back from the server because if I un-trust the cert I get a trust error. Could there be something I'm doing which strips it? I have a `MessageTranformer` plugged directly into my `HTTPS connnector` (nothing happening in between). Many thanks.

Comment: Just eliminated the server (switched from IIS to soapUI) and it still comes back with a null `PEER_CERTIFICATES`.

Comment: "Just eliminated the server (switched from IIS to soapUI)" <- what does this mean? Deos soapUI contain an HTTPS server you're connecting the `https:outbound-endpoint` to?

Comment: Yes that's right. I was connecting (from mule) to an IIS server and then tried it against a soapUI server - hoping it was a quirk of IIS but no joy. And like I say the server is definitely giving mule the cert because it throws a trust error if not in the trust store.

Comment: OK, then unfortunately, I don't know why this feature doesn't work :( Sorry.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help David. I might look into interceptors to see if that gives me any luck.